# Manipulate Tutorials?

Tags: manipulate, plotting

I am wanting to combine equations with sets of static data points in a manipulate and do the curve fitting by moving the slider bars on my independent variables. The best examples of this art may be found at: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=Normand

Could someone please point me to one or more detailed tutorials that would make me as good a Mathematica programmer as Mark D. Normand?

Comment: It's a terribly broad question, so I don't think it can be answered any better than in the post I linked to above.

Comment: How about the help files and tutorials for Manipulate?